# Magento "adminhtml/system_config_backend_image_favicon" Error

Tags: magento

I tried to install the Blank template in Magento and now get the following error printing when trying to access the Admin -> Configuration -> Design section.

```
Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_image_favicon

Trace:
#0 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(310): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
#1 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(204): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#3 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(77): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#4 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#5 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#6 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

I don't understand what the error is and a simple Google search brings nothing. I have another error when accessing the front end and that is as follows:

```
Invalid method Mage_Wishlist_Block_Links::addWishlistLink(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addWishlistLink', Array)
#1 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(347): Mage_Wishlist_Block_Links->addWishlistLink()
#2 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Array, Array)
#3 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(110): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage()
#8 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
#11 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match('index')
#12 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
#14 /home/trilight/public_html/magetest/index.php(80): Mage::run(Array)
#15 {main}
```

Any help will be so much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue but overriding wishlist.xml from the theme I’m using with the wishlist.xml from base/layout fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out. WTH! 1.4.2.0 'upgrade'?!?

Apparently it missed a bunch of files when it 'upgraded'. I assumed incorrectly that it was working and then tried to use 'design' today under configuration. Whoops.

I recommend reading this [post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/214063/#t287419).

..And for the favicon error specifically do this:

`wget http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.4/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php`

place Favicon.php relative to where you see it downloading from in your source.

(This had nothing to do with my end. All perms correct. I own this system. This was an incomplete upgrade per magento core via connect/pear.)

Edit:
Or easier if you dont want to keep finding problems (1.4.2.0):

1. Grab source:
   `wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.4.2.0/magento-1.4.2.0.tar.gz`
2. untar and change to magento/app/code/core

Be careful you copy carefully and understand next step(!) :

3. `cp -R * /{your_magento_site}/app/code/core`
4. The owner of these files may need to be chowned depending on credentials you copied files as...
5. All needed 'upgrade' files should now be in place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the var/cache and var/sessions directory ? That should fix this

Comment: This has not helped at all, still the same error message(s). Thank you for your response, though.

Comment: What if you try to disable wishlists in the admin panel System > Configuration > Customers > Wishlist = No

Comment: Also done this mate! I tried this before deleting the two folders in var.

Answer (score 0):

About the wishlist.xml problem, i had the same problem, disable it in system>configuration>advanced and/or use the whislist.xml from base/layout like Fooligan said.

I'm still searching for a solution for the "Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_image_favicon"

So, if someone fixed this....? ;)

Answer (score 0):

has that also happened to you after upgrading magento via connectmanager? I found interesting info saying I should reupload certain folders via ftp - anyone tried that?

Answer (score 0):

It happened after installing the Yoast seo blank theme through connectmanager on a new installation of magento (1.4.2.0)

I don't know if it would make a difference if you install the theme by uploading it via FTP?